# Ubuntu doesn´t recognize any of my disks

Tags: drivers, 19.04, raid, amd-processor, msi

Recently I have tried to setup RAID via hardware (B350 MSi motherboard for AMD) and tried to install Windows 10.

After installing the drivers has no problem with my disk on Windows, but trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 I can´t find a way to show me any drive.

[image: screen Ubuntu installation]

I tried to download and install the AMD drivers for Linux but I cannot install them, the system says that there are missing libs and I can´t update via terminal because of the "try ubuntu without installation" thing.

So I´m completely lost. I read something about change to AHCI mode but I don´t want to lose my Windows installation or undo the RAID.

The RAID drivers that I have tried: https://www.amd.com/es/support/chipsets/amd-socket-am4/b350

Comment: You install AHCI drivers into Windows then change UEFI settings. Asus B350M-A needs newer kernel that 18.04 default
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391892
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390660&p=13799816#post13799816
MSI Tomahawk B350 with Ryzen R5 1600 New UEFI required
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390475
ASUS PRIME B350M-E major issues
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-Raven-Ridge-Mobo-Linux

Comment: @oldfred: I guess your comment qualifies as an answer.